# size of a python file object and seek()

Tags: python, file, sys

I created a file with the following entry, returned by `file.read()`

'abcd\nefgh\n1234\nijkl\n5678\n\nend'

I open the file to read now, with 'f' as handler.
`f.read()` returns the above.
`f.tell()` returns 35L
`sys.getsizeof(f)` returns 76.
Trying to call `f.seek(offset)` with offset any higher than 35 returns nothing.

Python documentation says `file.seek()` moves in bytes. so is there a mismatch between what is returned by `sys.getsizeof()` and `f.tell()/seek()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sys.getsizeof() does not return the size of the file *on disk*. Instead, it returns the size that the file object (the interface to the real file on disk) takes up *in memory*.

You could even use sys.getsizeof() with objects that don't have any disk presence. For instacen, if `s = 'abcd'`, then calling `sys.getsizeof(s)` might return (depending on your implementation) 25, even though s is a string, and it doesn't any space on disk.

Answer (score 7):

`sys.getsizeof` returns a size of an object (i.e. how many bytes a `file` class instance takes up in the memory), and has nothing to do with the size of the file contents.

Answer (score 4):

```
# size of the file in bytes
size = os.path.getsize(pathname)
# another way
f = file(pathname)
size = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
```

### References

- [os.path.getsize](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.getsize#os.path.getsize)
- [os.fstat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.fstat#os.fstat)
- [f.fileno](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=fileno#file.fileno)